# Using Flask to transfer html form data to SQL database

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I am having an issue pulling data from an html form and transferring it into my SQL database with the help of Flask. I feel like I have tried everything including making a new route to send a message. The "tousername" and "message" are the ids for the form. Can anyone help me understand why the SQL database stores receiver = NULL and message = NULL when I run the following code?

```
@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form.get('message')
        receiver = request.form.get('tousername')
        new_message = Message(sender_id=current_user.id, receiver=receiver, message=message)
        db.session.add(new_message)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)

class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    receiver = db.Column(db.String(100))
    message = db.Column(db.String(100))
    time_sent = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
```

Comment: Did you map "tousername" and "message" to the name attribute of the input field? The data is serialized based on the name attribute. The id attribute is only used for possible identification, for example in connection with a label, javascript or css.

Comment: @Detlef, yes this solved the issue. Thank you so much!